# Django allauth Social application extra data

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-database, django-jsonfield

so I have set up Django allauth on my Django project and connected to Instagram,
when doing so I have now on my admin site Social accounts category with my account registers, all good so far

on the lower page, I can see a field called extra data,
how can I put it inside the normal Users database so I can use it to take how many followers I got out of the extra data?
can I request the followers with the Token i have maybe?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can simply access the `SocialAccount` model like any other django model:

```py
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount

def instagram(request):
    data = SocialAccount.objects.get(user=request.user).extra_data
    follows = data.get('counts')
    return render(request, 'Path.to.html', {"follows": follows})
```