# name 'SocialAccount' is not defined

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I want to access the `extra-data` dictionary provided by `SocialAccount`. I need to store the family name of the user in a variable. I have attached the the code below. The following code throws an error:

> name 'SocialAccount' is not defined.

I saw this on [Django allauth Social application extra data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51804368/django-allauth-social-application-extra-data/51805154#51805154).

```
data=SocialAccount.objects.get(user=request.user).extra_data
        follows=data.get('family_name')
        return render(request, 'main/index.html', {"name":follows})
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think you need to import the SocialAccount model in your file. Just do > from .models import SocialAccount

Comment: Yes , 'from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount' was the required import !. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the missing import:

```py
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount
```